# API Gateway + Lambda slow NOT due to cold start

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS Lambda setup with 3 Dockerised Python Lambda functions working together. 1 function hits the other 2 and then returns a response. It might work better with just 1 function, but 3 felt like a better way to separate concerns.

Testing this setup in Lambda's "test" tab returns responses reliably with no errors in average 1-6s.

This setup receives invocations via API Gateway. Testing with API Gateway's "test" function gives similar results to testing in Lambda. Again, average is <6s.

There is no cold-start problem that I can see. Possibly, the first invocation is slower, but the functions are small and don't take long to load. Also, the average time of <6s is found after several non-concurrent executions.

However, if I run this setup from my own PC (same region as all of the AWS resources), then the best average I can get is >16s per request. That's over several non-concurrent requests. The only difference I can see is that I am hitting API Gateway from outside AWS.

Does anyone know why this is happening, or how to improve the response speed? I've seen several similar SO posts, but they were mostly attributed to cold-start, which doesn't seem to be the problem if I am understanding correctly.

I've tried

- adding resource policies instead of role-based policies. Some articles suggested this would make a difference. No difference observed.
- set up API Gateway manually as well as from the Lambda console. Neither appeared to be faster.
- testing large volumes of data. Even after thousands of requests, the speed does not improve.
- allocating at least double the required memory. No difference.

Comment: I'd suggest to enable x-ray and look at cloudwatch logs to better understand how is the latency spread out.

Comment: How large is the data within a single response?

Comment: As suggested, adding logging to the functions to understand which parts of the lambda function are taking the majority of the time. Generally having one lambda synchronously invoke two other lambdas would not be a suggested pattern - you end up paying for twice the compute time (as lambda 1 is waiting for 2 and 3 to complete). You can achieve separation of concerns with different python functions all within the same lambda, but if you are truly doing 2 completely different tasks, then using 1 lambda to orchestrate those is possibly not a great option

Comment: Thanks! These are helpful suggestions. X-ray helped me see where the problem was. It seems that a small disparity in the test input data I was using was having a big impact downstream. The amount of data in each request is around 200-300bytes and the responses that come back are 50-60kb. It's a good point about double-paying for the lambda functions.